# Is there a difference between spawning multiple threads that runs to completion vs having a single thread wait for work?

Tags: c, pthreads

I'm writing a piece of software that does a single very long task.  To allow interruption, we have added a check-pointing function that periodically (on the order of minutes) dumps an image of the program state to disk.  This takes some time, however, so I would like to switch to a model where the checkpoints are written on a separate thread rather than blocking the primary worker.  (Yes, I know I need to keep it thread-safe.)

As I see it, there are two primary methods of accomplishing this task:

1. For each checkpoint, I `pthread_create()` a thread which will execute the checkpointing function once and then terminate.
2. For each checkpoint, I `pthread_cond_signal()` a single waiting thread that executes the checkpointing function and then returns to waiting.

Both methods require making an atomic copy of my working state and passing it to the checkpoint thread, as well as ensuring that the checkpoint complete successfully before I try another.

My question is if there is a compelling reason to use one method over the other.

Comment: What if your thread gets pulled off the processor more than once? Does this affect your results from the checkpointing func?

Comment: If you mean "executed more than once" simultaneously, that would be bad and I have to make sure that doesn't happen.  If you mean "rescheduled by the processor", it does not.  The implementation is to synchronously stage the state info to memory, from there the checkpoint function processes that info and dumps it to disk: it will have as long as it needs to complete, and a new state will only be sent to the staging area once the checkpoint process is confirmed as complete.  The primary work can continue on the live data without affecting the staging area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't go with continually creating/terminating/destroying/joining threads if you can possibly avoid it.  It's expensive in terms of latency and cycles, has the risk of unwanted multiple threads doing overlapping work and is difficult to debug.

Just create one thread once, at app startup, and don't terminate it. Loop it round some synchro object and sSignal it when you need to, or run a timer or sleep loop to perform your image dumps.

Comment: OK -- the tempting part of "just call `pthread_create(&t, func,data)`" is outweighed by the overhead and potential issues.  Thanks.

Comment: Seriously? According to the question, the creation of the extra thread is needed once every few minutes. Thread creation takes what, milliseconds, on a bad day and a bad OS?

Comment: @EOF - Takethe latency/cycles gain in as a bonus.  I didn't bother with reading the details of the question, I already had my answer formed up from the title.

Comment: So, now that you know, are you going to expand this answer to actually include an argument, rather than a knee-jerk "don't ever create one-time threads"?

Answer (score 2):

I would argue that `pthreads` are a bad fit for your requirements:
Regardless of whether you spawn a new thread for each backup or use a threadpool, you need to make a deep copy of your working-set, which is expensive. Also, you may need extensive synchronization if you go with the thread-pool. Instead, there's a much easier way to do it:
`fork()`.
The child process inherits the entire memory-space of the parent, but on modern OSs, the copy is lazy (`copy on write`). Also, you don't need to worry about cleaning up the thread you started, because the `fork()`ed child releases its resources when it terminates. If your original program is already multithreaded, you may wish to make sure to only use async-safe functions in the child, but thankfully `write()` is async-safe (as is `open()` and `unlink()`). To avoid your child turning into a zombie, you need to call `waitid(P_ALL, 0, siginfo_t *infop, WEXITED | WNOHANG)` in a loop until it returns nonzero or the `siginfo_t *` indicates that the child has not yet exited. This avoids stalling the parent in case the child is not done with the backup before the next backup-point is reached.

Comment: fork() is not available on all OS, notably Windows.

Comment: @MartinJames: Did you see the `pthreads`-tag under the question? I don't know about you, but that suggests the availability of `fork()` to me.